# Controling the occurrence of onChildAdded event in firebase database

Tags: android, events, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on android app in which I want to store unique IDs of users in firebase database, so to achieve this I have created a root, named "Users" and will store all the users unique IDs in this root.

So in order to check uniqueness I have to go through each child of "Users" and after checking the uniqueness I will add the uniqueID to "Users" root or will notify the user that uniqueId is not available.

**When I check uniqueness, it's conditionals (if/else) execute before occurrence of OnChildAdded event, How to execute some code(mentioned in my code) after occurrence of OnChildAdded event**

My Code

```
postBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!uniqueIdText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    uniqueness = true;
                    users.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(uniqueIdText.getText().toString().trim()))
                                uniqueness = false;

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }

                    });
                }
                else if(uniqueIdText.getText().toString().trim().equals("") )
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please enter id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //======================How to execute it(code below) after occurrence of OnChildAdded event====================
                    if (uniqueness){
                        DatabaseReference usersInfo = users.child(uniqueIdText.getText().toString().trim());
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!uniqueIdText.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "ID not available, Please enter a new one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know when all the `onChildAdded` events have been called. But you can know when the first data from the database has been synchronized by using a `ValueEventListener`.

But in this case, I'd **highly** recommend taking a different approach. Downloading all UIDs to check if one value is present is incredibly inefficient and won't scale. Instead, attach a listener to the specific UID that you're looking for. If that value exists, you'll get the value. If it doesn't exist, you'll get an empty snapshot:

```
users.child(uniqueIdText.getText().toString()).addSingleValueEventListener(@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            uniqueness = false;
        }
        else {
            uniqueness = true;
        }
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
```